# Beam finite element stiffness matrix from section constitutive matrix

Tags: finite-element

I'm trying to construct the 12 x 12 beam element stiffness matrix from a section constitutive matrix (6 x 6 with shear stiffnesses, axial stiffness, bending stiffnesses and torsional stiffness on the diagonal). I can get a 6 x 6 beam element matrix as would be used in a multibody formulation using the method described here:

Malcolm, David J., and Daniel L. Laird. "Modeling of blades as equivalent beams for aeroelastic analysis." ASME 2003 Wind Energy Symposium. American Society of Mechanical Engineers, 2003.

However, I want to use the 6 x 6 matrix that comes out of that process in a conventional finite element model which needs a 12 x 12 matrix. Is there a simple method of converting between the two? I've found information for a simple stiffness matrix but mine is fully populated as it's for a composite beam with lots of material couplings.

For a two-noded beam element, the element stiffness matrix $K$ relates the generalized forces $f$ to the generalized displacements $u$, i.e., $f = Ku$.
In matrix form
$$
  \begin{bmatrix} f_{x1} \\ f_{y1} \\ f_{z1} \\ m_{x1} \\ m_{y1} \\ m_{z1} \\
        f_{x2} \\ f_{y2} \\ f_{z2} \\ m_{x2} \\ m_{y2} \\ m_{z2}
  \end{bmatrix}
  = \begin{bmatrix} K_{1,1} & K_{1,2} & \dots & K_{1,12} \\
                    K_{1,2} & K_{2,2} & \dots & K_{2,12} \\
                    \vdots  & \vdots  & \ddots & \vdots  \\
                    K_{1,12} & K_{2,12} & \dots & K_{12,12} \\
    \end{bmatrix}
    \begin{bmatrix} u_{x1} \\ u_{y1} \\ u_{z1} \\ \theta_{x1} \\ \theta_{y1} \\ \theta_{z1} \\
        u_{x2} \\ u_{y2} \\ u_{z2} \\ \theta_{x2} \\ \theta_{y2} \\ \theta_{z2}
  \end{bmatrix} 
$$
where $f_x, f_y, f_z$ are forces, $m_x, m_y, m_z$ are moments, $u_x, u_y, u_z$ are displacements, and $\theta_x, \theta_y, \theta_z$ are rotations.

The section stiffness $S$ relates the generalized forces at a point in the beam to the generalized strains at that location, i.e., $f = S\varepsilon$. In matrix form,
$$
 \begin{bmatrix} f_{x} \\ f_{y} \\ f_{z} \\ m_{x} \\ m_{y} \\ m_{z} 
  \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} S_{1,1} & S_{1,2} & \dots & S_{1,6} \\
                    S_{2,1} & S_{2,2} & \dots & S_{2,6} \\
                    \vdots  & \vdots  & \ddots & \vdots  \\
                    S_{6,1} & S_{6,2} & \dots & S_{6,6} \\
    \end{bmatrix}
    \begin{bmatrix} \gamma_x \\ \gamma_y \\ \varepsilon_z \\ \kappa_x \\ \kappa_y \\ \kappa_z \end{bmatrix}
$$
where $\gamma_x,\gamma_y$ are shear strains, $\varepsilon_z$ is a normal strain, and $\kappa_x,\kappa_y,\kappa_z$ are curvatures.  These strains are defined as
$$
 \gamma_x = \frac{\partial u_x}{\partial z} - \theta_y \ , \ 
 \gamma_y = \frac{\partial u_y}{\partial z} + \theta_x \ , \ 
 \varepsilon_z = \frac{\partial u_z}{\partial z} \ , \ 
 \kappa_x = \frac{\partial \theta_x}{\partial z} \ , \
 \kappa_y = \frac{\partial \theta_y}{\partial z} \ , \
 \kappa_z = \frac{\partial \theta_z}{\partial z} \ .
$$

Integration of the above relations and then evaluation at the two nodes will probably lead to the beam stiffness matrix, but it is not clear how that should be done.

Comment: Is this a well-posed problem?  You appear to seek the average properties of a potentially complex beam from properties of a single section.

Comment: Thanks for the edit Biswajit. The question was posted from my phone so maths was tricky! When integrating $f = S\varepsilon$, what should the bounds on the integration be? Is $K$ made up from four sub quadrants with different bounds (0 to L, -L to 0 or something) or is it more complex than that? As far as the problem being well posed is concerned, it is fairly standard practice to model wind turbine blades in this way but I know it isn't perfect! Usually the beam is considered to be fairly simple, with perhaps a shear centre offset and an elastic centre offset.

Comment: @BiswajitBanerjee

Comment: Consider an Euler-Bernoulli beam.  You will need at least two linear elements to represent the deformation of the beam accurately.  I suspect that same thing applies in your case, i.e., you'll have to break your beam up into elements, each with a different section stiffness. For each section you will have six equations of the form $\int_y \int_z \sigma_x dz dy = S_{11}(\partial u_x/\partial z - \theta_y) + \dots$ using the definition of [stress resultant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stress_resultants). The lhs indicates that the bounds of integration are $-h$ to $h$ for $z$.

Comment: In the above comment, the expansion of the left had side is just to illustrate how the average force and average moment are computed.  In your case, the implicit assumption seems to be that all forces/moments are per unit width.